# Queue implementation as Array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, queue

So I was required to do an implementation of queue in arrays, and I wasn't having any trouble till I saw I was getting a funny output after I dequeue and try to enqueue another value...

For example (output):

```
Queue: [1]     //Enqueue 1  
Queue: [1, 2]  //Enqueue 2
Queue: [2]      //Dequeue
Queue: [2, 2]   //Enqueue 3
Queue: [2, 2, 3] //Enqueue 4
Queue: [5, 2, 3, 4]  //Now is a total mess...
```

My code contains queue, dequeque and resize methods everything was working fine and I really don't have any idea at all of how to fix it anymore...
Here's my code with the main if you want to try it. Thanks.

```
public class MainQueue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int capacity=5;
        Queue<Integer> queue = new Queue<Integer>(capacity);

        queue.enqueue(1);
        System.out.println("Queue: "+ queue);
        queue.enqueue(2);
        System.out.println("Queue: "+ queue);
        queue.dequeue();
        queue.enqueue(3);
        System.out.println("Queue: "+ queue);
        queue.enqueue(4);
        System.out.println("Queue: "+ queue);
        queue.enqueue(5);
        System.out.println("Queue: "+ queue);

    }
}
```

Class

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;


public class Queue<E> {
    private E[] elements;//array in generic
    private int front;//first element or front of the queue
    private int back;//last element or back of the queue
    private int capacity; //capacity of the queue
    private int count; //indicates number of elements currently stored in the queue

    public Queue(int size)
    {
        capacity = size;
        count = 0;
        back = size-1;
        front = 0;
        elements =(E []) new Object[size];  //queue array empty
    }

    //Returns true if the queue is empty or false
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return count==0;//means its true
    }

    //Add elements to the queue
    public void enqueue(E item)
    {
        if(count == capacity)
        {
            resize(capacity*2);
            // System.out.println("Queue is full");

        }

        back =(back+1) % capacity;    //example back=(0+1)%10=1
        elements[back]=item;
        //elements[0]=0
        //item=elements[count];
        count++;
    }


    //Public resize
    public void resize(int reSize){
        E[] tmp = (E[]) new Object[reSize];

        int current = front;
        for (int i = 0; i &lt; count; i++)
        {
            tmp[i] = elements[current];
            current = (current + 1) % count;
        }

        elements = tmp;
        front = 0;
        back = count-1;
        capacity=reSize;

    }


    //Dequeue method to remove head
    public E dequeue()
    {
        if(isEmpty())
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Dequeue: Queue is empty");
        else
        {
            count--;
            for(int x = 1; x <= count; x++)
            {
                elements[x-1] = elements[x];
            }
            capacity--;
            return (E) elements;
        }
    }

    //peek the first element
    public E peek()
    {
        if(isEmpty())
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Peek: Queue is empty");

        else
        return elements[front];
    }


    //Print queue as string
    public String toString()
    {

        if(isEmpty()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Queue is empty");
        }

        String s = "[";
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if(i != 0)
            s += ", ";
            s = s + elements[i];// [value1,value2,....]
        }

        s +="]";
        return s;
    }

    public void delete() {   //Delete everything
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you reduce the capacity when you dequeue?

Comment: This works as expected on my machine... I get [1], [1,2], [2], [2,3], [2,3,4], and [2,3,4,5].

Comment: Thats weird because I keep on getting repeated numbers and numbers placed in a random index...where did you tried it?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I actually thought about that, but still even if I take it off doesnt make any difference, because when I resize the capacity gets modified, anyways yes, i should take it off...

Comment: @LilithDeficiency, never mind. It doesn't work if your initial capacity is big enough for initial dequeue. If you set capacity to 2, it seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are updating the `back` in the `enqueue()` method using the current value of `back`, but you aren't updating it in the `dequeu()` method at all. That is not going to work correctly. In fact, you should rather calculate `back` based on `count`.

Just change:

```
back = (back + 1) % capacity;
```

to:

```
back = count % capacity;
```

Comment: Thankkkkk youuuu sir, you made my day! this works! :)

Answer (score 1):

In `dequeue` you are not updating the `back` variable that determines the position on which you add new value with `enqueue`. Furthermore in dequque you could copy nonexistent value on index `0` from index `1` when you have `count` just of `1`. This is a special case that will make out of bounds error if you made a queue with capacity(size) of 1, enqueued something and then dequeued it.